# Centring an element above another element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

struggling to centre my `icon` above the text, the height of the icon is fine but it should sit like so:

tried using flex but couldn't find the correct solution.

[image]

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.icon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="icon"></div>
    <p class="text">We couldn't find any matches to your search. <br></br>Please try again.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You haven't applied any centering to the icon. Put your text alignment on the parent element instead of just the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS flexbox: but remember that the default direction is `row`. If you switch it to `flex-direction: column`, then you will achieve what you want:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.icon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="icon"></div>
    <p class="text">We couldn't find any matches to your search. <br />Please try again.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Surely you know that this is a manifold duplicate.

Comment: @isherwood None of the solutions you closed the question with uses `flex-direction: column`

Comment: Then consider adding that solution to the duplicate. The issue is still the same.

Comment: There are more questions using flex-direction:column that we don't really need here. margin:auto is enough